# Delphi XE4 - Get current monitor of form

Tags: delphi

On a multi monitor environment, I want to be able to get the current monitor and the active monitor when closing the form in order to save the info and when the form is reopened at a later time, the form to be displayed in the last place it was displayed.

When form is showed, I do all the checking (if monitor number -i- exists and so on), and if all is ok, I display the form on the right monitor (i)

```
Form1.BoundsRect := Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect;
```

I want to be able to get the current monitor the form is displayed on and the active monitor in Form1.onCloseQuery event so I could save that info in some Ini, DB, whatever, but it seems I cannot find the right method to do it properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Screen has 'MonitorFromPoint' and 'MonitorFromRect' and 'MonitorFromWindow'. TForm has '.Monitor'

Comment: I recently blogged on the subject. My code does exactly what you ask. See [http://francois-piette.blogspot.be/2014/03/persistent-form-with-f11-to-fullscreen.html](http://francois-piette.blogspot.be/2014/03/persistent-form-with-f11-to-fullscreen.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wish to save the form's position, you can do so in screen coordinates. Save information in `TForm.BoundsRect` which gives you **screen relative** coordinates. Note that the screen relative coordinates encompass all monitors attached to the screen.

In other words, you don't actually need to worry about which monitor the form is on. For instance, suppose you had two 800x600 monitors, side-by-side. The screen coordinates would be:

- (0, 0, 800, 800) for the left hand monitor.
- (800, 0, 1600, 800) for the right hand monitor.

What is sensible is for you to check whether or not your form is within the bounds of the screen when you first show it. Perhaps when you remembered its position, it was on a monitor that has subsequently been removed. Or perhaps the user has reconfigured their monitors to render your previous screen coordinates invalid.

To answer the question that you asked, find the monitor associated with a form using the form's [`Monitor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Monitor) property. This is implemented with a call to the Win32 API function [`MonitorFromWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145064.aspx) passing `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST`.

Comment: If the monitor was removed then I will position the form onDesktopCenter of Monitor[0]. But it would be much easier to know the monitorNo, left&top coords on that monitor, and if all is ok (monitor present, form dimensions and position within bounds) display the form accordingly. Can you give some code example on how to retrieve the MonitorNo of the form, please?

Comment: Why it is not a stable property? Because user can change monitor arrangement?

Comment: But that's of no real use to you. And will give you an AV if you try it when your form is off screen. Because `Monitor` can be `nil`.

Comment: What you want to do is test if `Form.Monitor` is `nil`. If it is, then you form is off-screen. Monitor numbers do not retain meaning from one run of your program to the next. An obvious example. Your program is on monitor 2. The program closes. The user removes monitor 2.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code of the way you would do it properly and AV free?

Comment: :) That one I know. I was talking about a proper way to search the form's monitor using the overlapping method you mentioned.

Comment: `not Assigned(Form.Monitor)` is better, I think. That's how I do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was just trying to use this but I found that my left monitor is actually monitor 2.  It appears that Delphi gives you physical monitor numbers rather than the logical ones. So none of these related posts are helping me :-)